# Getting column names from DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am dynamically generating a select in an html form.  The purpose is to be able to swap out visible datatable columns for invisible datatable columns.  Firstly, I'm not sure how to accomplish the actual switching.

My main question is how to get the column names. I've tried `window.table.api().columns()[0];` and `window.table.api().columns().data()[0];` (I know how the `[0]` index works, `[0]` is my way of representing that I'd be iterating through.  Does anyone know how to get the names of these columns?

Here's an example of how my constructor looks:

```
   window.table =
            $table.dataTable({
                'ajax': {
                    'url': '/api/v1/data',
                    "type": "GET"
                },
                /**
                 * Specify which columns we're going to show
                 */
                columns:             {
                  data: 'Visible',
                  name: 'Visible',
                  visible: true
                  },
                    {
                    data: 'dataName',
                    name: 'Invisible',
                     visible: false
                },
                /**
                 * we want to disable showing page numbers, but still limit the number of results
                 */
                "dom": "t",
                /**
                 * let's disable some dynamic custom css
                 */
                asStripClasses: [],
                /**
                 * let's keep the pages reasonable to prevent scrolling
                 */
                pageLength: 8
            });
```

Comment: you want something like that https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/24690/getting-list-of-column-names ?

Comment: @mayk that's deprecated.  This question is tagged 1.10

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of looking those names with the Datatables API, you can get the names of the columns using [JQuery selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) through the DOM like this:

```
   //Replace yourTableId with the corresponding Id
    $("#yourTableId thead tr th").each(function(){
        alert(this.innerHTML); //This executes once per column showing your column names!
    });
```

I have tested it against https://datatables.net/ sample table (where yourTableId=example).

### EDIT:

Since the OP said that he wanted to find the columns that are not visible and those columns are not directly accessible through the DOM, the solution results something like this:

```
    //fill with the appropiate constructor
    var table = $('#yourTableId').DataTable();

    //iterate through every column in the table.
    table.columns().every( function () {        
            var visible = this.visible();
            if (!visible)
                alert(this.header().innerHTML);
    });
```

Sources:

[columns.every()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns().every())

[column.visible()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().visible())

Regards!

Comment: Please see question, that doesn't help with hidden columns

Comment: Well your question wasnt clear enough, can you provide a sample code?